# Is it possible to damage my computer by installing an old HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I found an old 1TB HDD in my basement. I don't remember why I removed it from and older PC the past - maybe because it was failing, or maybe because of a computer upgrade. I'm not sure it has always been dust-free and handled with care.

Is there any risk connecting an old HDD to my PC and see if it's still alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always risk if you connect *anything* to your PC, but I'd say that dust is no problem; if the hard drive casing isn't damaged, the dust has no way to get inside. Hard drives are designed to keep out small particles because they'd damage the drive surfaces if they could get in. Also, dust usually isn't conductive, so even if you have dust in the drive itself, it shouldn't damage anything but the hard drive itself.

Humidity might be a risk factor; if there are corroded parts in the power lines inside the drive, it might produce a short. But I think it's unlikely. I've connected ten-year-old hard drives I'd stored in less-than-ideal conditions to my PC and apart from some of them failing with unreadable sectors, I've never had problems.

Answer (score 2):

The chances that any problems the drive had will adversely affect your computer hardware are just about zero. It's really tough for problems in the electronics to cause damaging voltages to appear at the interface connector, and nothing else the drvie does could damage your machine. Even if it puts a dead short across your power supply, that is hardly ever a problem - at worst, remove the drive, do a hard-power-off (flip the hard power switch or unplug the computer from the wall), wait about five minutes (to allow the power supply's "crowbar" circuit to drain), and power up again. Computer PSUs are *extremely* robust.

A remote possibility: The HD has a virus on it. Solution: Don't boot from it, don't run any programs from it.

If you are still concerned, connect it to a hard drive enclosure with a USB interface instead (it's even more tough for bad voltages to get a) to the hard drive's interface connector and then b) through the USB interface).

Answer (score 0):

Connecting old SATA HDDs is fairly low risk operation, but if you want to minimize the risk, use an external USB-SATA dock. 
The most likely (still very unlikely) problem that might occur is your OS corrupting the data on the drive. This can be mitigated by mounting the drive read-only with eg. Linux live-CD/USB-stick.

Comment: Note that to serve this purpose, it needs to be USB, it can't be eSATA.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling why? also the answer never mentioned of eSATA?

Comment: @TomYan You'll notice I wasn't arguing against the point made in the answer. eSATA extends the SATA interface so provides no real isolation circuitry and thus provides no benefit over a plain internal SATA connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to damage your computer by installing an old HDD - in case you break something in your PC while connecting the disk :) 
But a connected HDD will not damage your computer.